# SonarQube Wrapper stopped -> Failure -> Mac OS Big Sur

Tags: macos, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, macos-big-sur

> SonarQube Wrapper stopped

(base) Kalidosss-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ sh /Applications/SonarQube/bin/macosx-universal-64/sonar.sh console
Running SonarQube...
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | WrapperSimpleApp: Encountered an error running main: java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
jvm 1    | java.lang.IllegalStateException: SonarQube requires Java 11 to run
jvm 1    |  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:508)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.App.checkJavaVersion(App.java:93)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.App.start(App.java:56)
jvm 1    |  at org.sonar.application.App.main(App.java:97)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
jvm 1    |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
jvm 1    |  at org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp.run(WrapperSimpleApp.java:240)
jvm 1    |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped

Comment: Your root cause is described in the error message: `SonarQube requires Java 11 to run`. You may be using too new Java version - check it with `java -version`.

Comment: Thank you for your response first. 
```
(base) Kalidosss-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)
(base) Kalidosss-MacBook-Pro:~ admin$ ```

Comment: So it's Java 8. You need to have Java 11 to run SonarQube.